# Non-Unital Ring Homomorphism from $M_2(\Bbb{C})$ to $M_2(\Bbb{C})$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Does there exist a nonzero ring homomorphism from $M_2(\Bbb{C})$ to itself that doesn't map the identity to the identity?

If so, I could use some help in constructing it. If not, I could use some help in disproving that such a map exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider a non-unital ring homomorphism  $\phi$ from $M_2(\Bbb C)$
to itself. It takes the identity $I$ to an idempotent element $E$,
by assumption not $O$ or $I$. All elements in the image commute with $E$.
But $E$ is conjugate to a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $0$ and
$1$. Therefore the only elements commuting with $E$ are polynomials in $E$, so the image of $\phi$ is commutative.

But the kernel of $\phi$ is a two-sided ideal of $M_2(\Bbb C)$. But $M_2(\Bbb C)$ is simple: its only two-sided ideals are $\{O\}$ and itself. Its image is non trivial, so its kernel must be $\{O\}$. But
then its image is isomorphic $M_2(\Bbb C)$, but also is commutative....